# Renaming all worksheets to the same name within folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder full of CSV files. They all have the same data structure and there's only one worksheet per workbook. They all have different worksheet names, usually a date. I would like to convert all of the worksheet names to exactly the same across all workbooks, something like "RenamedSheet" (or anything really). The code I have changes the worksheet name to the name of the workbook. I just want one worksheet name across all of the workbooks selected.

```
Sub RenameSheet()

Dim CurrentBook As Workbook
Dim ImportFiles As FileDialog
Dim FileCount As Long 'Count of workbooks selected
Dim wbName As String

'Open File Picker
Set ImportFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With ImportFiles
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Pick Files to Adjust"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add ".xlsx files", "*.xlsx"
    .Show
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Cycle through books
For FileCount = 1 To ImportFiles.SelectedItems.Count
    Set CurrentBook = Workbooks.Open(ImportFiles.SelectedItems(FileCount))
        wbName = Replace(CurrentBook.Name, ".xlsx", "") ' had to rework this line to the original
        CurrentBook.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Name = wbName
        CurrentBook.Close True
Next FileCount ' had to change this to FileCount to remove the error "invalid next control variable"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

How do I change my code so that it renames all of the worksheets in the selected workbooks to let us say "Renamesheet"

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "I have a folder full of CSV files"- do you though?  Looks more like you have a folder of Excel workbooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace the relevant part of your code with the following.

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

'Cycle through books
For FileCount = 1 To ImportFiles.SelectedItems.Count
    Set CurrentBook = Workbooks.Open(ImportFiles.SelectedItems(FileCount))
        ' Excel activates the CurrentBook on Open
        With CurrentBook
            ' if there is only one sheet its index must be 1
            .Sheets(1).Name = "New Name"
            .Close True
        End With
Next FileCount

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With
```